# How can i render html with using geckoview?

Tags: android, html, rendering, geckoview

I wanted to download a html file from a website first and edit that website and print that html with geckoview render engine

I know how to fetch a html and parse it but i don't know how to render it with using the renderengine

Geckoview just uses a url of a website

I don't want to use webview because i don't think it's not that good to make my own web browser app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeckoSession` has [`loadString(String htmlString, String mimeType)`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.html#loadString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method:

```
GeckoSession geckoSession = ...;// here you start session in your GeckoView
geckoSession.loadString(yourHTMLString, "text/html");
```

Comment: is it possible to open flash content using gecko @Vladyslav?

Comment: @gumuruh if you have a question - **ask a question**, don;t try asking it in comments

Answer (score 1):

geckoSession.loadData("My First Heading. My first paragraph.".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),"text/html");

Answer (score 0):

`geckoSession.loadString("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>","text/html")` **displays blank page. Awesome!**

Comment: Please edit your post and let people know where you're facing issue?